# The element appears only when clicked in a certain place

Tags: python, python-3.x, flutter, dart, selenium-webdriver

The essence of the problem is that the page is written in the Flutter framework. I need to use Selenium to click on the  field, but I can't get its XPATH until I click on the field.
[page before click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQm6Z.jpg)
[page after click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Rda.jpg)

When I hover the mouse over the field, the cursor value changes from default to text.
Maybe you can somehow move the mouse using Selenium to relative coordinates and make a click?
Or maybe you need to make some manipulations with the JS file when loading the page?

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 1):

We can't give you a complete answer without access to the page or at least the relevant HTML before and after the click. The basic answer is that you need to click element #1 (the "Paste here or type..." area) to expose element #2 (the TEXTAREA element in the screenshot) then use `.sendkeys()` to input the desired text.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to:

1. Click "//flt-text-editing-host"
2. Wait and type in "//flt-text-editing-host//input"

This is with the assumption that "//flt-text-editing-host" is clickable and it will trigger the display of the input element.